# Foundation 6 site only works in chrome?

Tags: jquery, firefox, safari, zurb-foundation

For some reason a site that I'm currently building for a client is only working in Chrome. In Firefox and Safari I am getting console errors in Foundation's javascript.

In Safari:

```
"SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')'"
```

and the related code is:

```
"$(window).on('resize.zf.mediaquery', () => {"...
```

and the code wrapping that is:

```
_watcher() {
$(window).on('resize.zf.mediaquery', () => {
  var newSize = this._getCurrentSize();

  if (newSize !== this.current) {
    // Broadcast the media query change on the window
    $(window).trigger('changed.zf.mediaquery', [newSize, this.current]);

    // Change the current media query
    this.current = newSize;
  }
});
```

In Firefox:

```
"SyntaxError: missing ; before statement"
```

and the related code is:

```
"let id = $(this).data('close');"...
```

and the code wrapping that is:

```
// Elements with [data-close] will close a plugin that supports it when clicked.
// If used without a value on [data-close], the event will bubble, allowing it to close a parent component.
$(document).on('click.zf.trigger', '[data-close]', function() {
let id = $(this).data('close');
if (id) {
triggers($(this), 'close');
}
else {
$(this).trigger('close.zf.trigger');
}
});
```

As you can see they both have a "zf" variable in them and the Foundation files are being called first... I have an idea that this may have something to do with Foundation's use of ECMAScript2015, but i'm gulping all my Foundation js with a Babel pipe... Has anyone else encountered this? Thanks so much for any insight.

Answer (score 0):

had to include mediaQuery.js after foundation.core.js